Continuants of a matrix continued fraction
Given an ordinary continued fraction
\begin{equation}
    x=b_0+\dfrac{a_1}{b_1+\dfrac{a_2}{b_2+...}}
\end{equation}
One can always define its continuants as $\frac{p_0}{q_0}=b_0$, $\frac{p_1}{q_1}=\frac{b_1b_0+a_1}{b_1}$, etc [See
Wiki ]
They fulfill a three-term recurrence relation and it can be shown that
\begin{equation}
    x=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{p_n}{q_n}
\end{equation}
Question: Is the same applicable for a matrix continued fraction?
If I have
\begin{equation}
    X=B_0+\dfrac{A_1}{B_1+\dfrac{A_2}{B_2+...}}
\end{equation}
being $A_n$ and $B_n$ non-commuting matrices, can I define the same continuants
$\frac{P_0}{Q_0}=B_0$, $\frac{P_1}{Q_1}=\frac{B_1B_0+A_1}{B_1}$, etc?
Where now $\frac{1}{X}=X^{-1}$ (assuming the inverse exists). And that they fulfil a (matrix) three-term recurrence relation and that
\begin{equation}
    X=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{P_n}{Q_n}
\end{equation}
I have not found any literature on that and I am quite surprised, as it seems like a natural generalization for a continued fraction.
Edit: I found a reference where answer my question, and it turn out to be correct.

$\frac{P_n}{Q_n}$ is ambiguous. It could mean $Q_n^{-1}P_n$ or $P_nQ_n^{-1}$.

You are right, and this might be the main problem behind trying to generalize the concept of continuants into matrices

@AnneBauval It turns out the correct way to define it is $Q_n^{-1}P_n$. In my edit, I put the reference

This is one way to define it. I cannot see in this reference the desired result "If $X=\dots$ [then] $X=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{P_n}{Q_n}$", which, I think, should rather be formulated as follows: "$A_n,B_n$ being matrices such that $\dots$, if $P_n,Q_n$ are defined by the three-term recurrence relation $\dots$, then $(Q_n^{-1}P_n)$ converges".

It is true they do not specify it, but they claim: "The continued fraction $K(B_n/A_n)$ converges in... if $F_n=(P_n/Q_n )=(Q^{−1}n P_n)$ converges... in the sense that there exists a matrix $F$... such that $\lim{n\rightarrow\infty}||F_n − F|| = 0.$

This definition (of the convergence of a sequence of matrices) is standard and doesn't help us.
